# how to fix this error: cannot read property '0' of undefined

Tags: node.js, express

when i get response from server and check validate api params lib @hapi/Joi when i check api params throw code they show me error: cannot read property '0' of undefined?

this is a node.js server using express.js library
when i comment this code and check api in postman my code prefectly running!

```
//validate api params
            const {error} = apiParamsSchema.schema({adminUsername,adminPassword});
             // console.log(adminPassword);
                if(error){
                    return res.status(400).json({
                        success: false,
                        message: error.details[0].message
                    });
                }
```

my expectation of this code is 10/10 because the same code run another server they dont show me error all code is good and prefectly running in another server

Comment: Your `error ` object doesnt have `details` key. Just print `console.log(error.details)` and see

Comment: same it does not work

Comment: What doesnt work??

Comment: my code throw same error is this another way ?

Comment: Can you post what you have tried??

Comment: //validate api params
            const {error} = apiParamsSchema.schema({adminUsername,adminPassword});
             // console.log(adminPassword);
                if(error){
                    return res.status(400).json({
                        success: false,
                        message: error.details[0].message
                    });
                }

Comment: You have posted the same you posted in question..What you havre tried newly and concluded its also not working??

Comment: whole code they show me some error the error is : error: cannot read property '0' of undefined

Answer (score 0):

I think your error object does not contain the details key. So you can replace code like that:-

```
message: error.details ? error.details[0].message : "Some error message"/error
```

If you don't want to specify a hardcoded error message then you can simply return the error.

Comment: message: error.details != undefined &&  error.details[0] != undefined? error.details[0].message : "Some error message"/error  ....Use this statement. this might help.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah you probably don't have `error.details[0]`. Another option on top of the above is to simply edit your code to

```
return res.status(400).json({
                        success: false,
                        message: error
                    });
```

That way, you will see the whole error object and you can trim  down your message key: value pair to something say `message: error.details` or `message: error.details.message` depending on the actual server response